# Find all indexes of zero in an array

Tags: python, indexing

Input: array=[3, 4, 7, 0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 3, 0] or any integer array.
Output: 3, 6, 9

```
    arr = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0]
    item = 0
    index1 = arr.index(item)
    start1=(index1+1)
    index2 = arr.index(item,start1)
    start2=(index2+1)
    index3 = arr.index(item,start2)
    print(index1)
    print(index2)
    print(index3)
```

I don't know how to find the index except for the index. Help those to do so that would find all the indexes of zero.

Comment: How about iterating through the array and testing each element for the desired value, and if true, save the index?

Comment: "I don't know how to find the index except for the index." -- I don't understand what you're trying to say here. What does your code output as result? What do you want as result instead? As a new user here, please also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
arr = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0]
indexes = [] # list which contains the indexes of zeros
for i, v in enumerate(arr): # Iterate over indexes and values (i and v)
    if (not v): # Equivalent to if (v == 0) in the case of an integer array
        indexes.append(i)
```

At the end you will have in `indexes` all the indexes of the zeros of `arr`:

```
>>> indexes
[1, 4, 7]
```

---

I would suggest you to read the documentation about [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to better understand the code.

Comment: Fit. I needed indexes in the form of numbers. But that's okay too. Thank you very much. And for suggest too<3

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a generator as follows:

```
array = [3, 4, 7, 0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 3, 0]

print(', '.join(str(i) for i, v in enumerate(array) if v == 0))
```

**Output:**

```
3, 6, 9
```